# Error: arguments imply differing number of rows, but I know they're the same number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to use a for loop with read_table to read a list of files into the same data frame, column-wise. I have tried using read_table on them each individually (there's 3 text files, once I take out the first one which I don't want) and it's clear they're all the same number of rows (2,946). Here's the code:

```
te <- list.files("UCI HAR Dataset/test")
te <- te[-1] 
testdf <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3){
    testdf <- cbind(testdf, read_table(te[i]))
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 2946
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that the original, empty data frame has no rows, but this method has worked for me in the past. Is there a better way to do this so I don't run into this error?

Comment: `test_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(te, read_table))` or `test_df <- purrr::map_dfr(te, read_table)` which is safer if columns don't match

Comment: Ok, I used the first solution, but instead of using rbind, I used cbind, since I needed to attach them by column not by row. That seems to have worked, thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't read carefully. The purrr version would be `purrr:::map_dfc()` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used

```
test_df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(te, read_table, col_names = FALSE))
```